# Yii2 init error on PHP7

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've a problem when i try to switch my project from dev enviroment to prod, the project is a git repository I push to my server, now I need to switch to production and I try to run`php init` on server but all time I receive the same error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /my/root/path/init on line 70
```

where /my/root/path/ is the base path where I push code.

Someone have any idea about this error?

Comment: Show the code around line 70

Comment: Sorry, this is the code: `array_walk($skipFiles, function(&$value) use($env, $root) { $value = "$root/$value"; });` like I have seen is according to PHP documentation

Comment: What is the PHP version on the target server?

Comment: The version is PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Based on my previous answer and the comment:

> Try
>
> ```
> array_walk($skipFiles, function(&$value, $key, $data) {
>     $value = $data[1] . '/' . $value;
> }, [$env, $root]);
> ```
>
> **@Marber**: Return the same error, a similar solution is `function resolveBug($value) { $value = "$root/$value"; } array_walk($skipFiles, resolveBug($value));` and this resolve the bug but the procedure generate anothe error on line 81: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['... and the code is $callbacks = ['setCookieValidationKey', 'setWritable', 'setExecutable', 'createSymlink'];`

I'm guessing there is PHP 7 on the CGI side and CLI is PHP < 5.3 and that is why console commands don't work.

Check your console PHP version by running

```
php -v
```

in console.

Comment: Return the same error, a similar solution is                                                    `function resolveBug($value) {`                                                           `$value = "$root/$value";`                                                                               `}`
 `array_walk($skipFiles, resolveBug($value));` and this resolve the bug but  the procedure generate anothe error on line 81: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['...` and the code is `$callbacks = ['setCookieValidationKey', 'setWritable', 'setExecutable', 'createSymlink'];`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I know the problem, I have generate on server an application with CGI PHP 7.0 but when I run `php init` I think the execution is handled by php 5.2.17, the version returned by  `php -v`. Thanks for the support!